# Windows wants me to install a fingerprint reader driver - but I don't have one

Tags: windows-7, drivers, fingerprint

I've been getting a persistent warning in Windows 7 that I need to install a fingerprint reader driver.  This is absurd because my computer does not have a fingerprint reader!  Is there a way to make it stop giving me these warnings?  I mean, I could let it install the driver anyhow, but what's the point of installing drivers for a device I plainly don't have?

Comment: Could you post exact text of the warning or a link to the screenshot?

Comment: It would also help if you could provide us the computer model.

Comment: It's a Dell Precision M6600.  I tried to screenshot the warning message, but as soon as you hit any key it goes away.  The message text is just: "Install your fingerprint reader driver".  It appears in the Action Center in the task bar every time I boot or wake up the computer after hibernation.

Comment: This seems fishy to me. It is not in device manager, yet you are getting messages that disappear after you hit any key. I would run a virus scan and would not install the driver.

Answer (score 1):

You could enter setup and disable it under the security tab.

edit:Press F2 during boot to enter setup. This is a basic UEFI implementation, there should be a list on the left hand side with + boxes to click on and expand the list. There should be an option either under security or under system config>misc devices.

Comment: Could you expand on how one would do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yep! Try this:

> Right Click on the computer icon.
>   Click Manage > Device Manager
>   Select the Fingerprint reader and then right-click > disable

That should do the trick. Hopefully!

Comment: I've looked through every branch of the tree in the Device Manager, and the Fingerprint reader does not show up.  (Not surprising since there isn't one...)